# Why serverSocket.accept() doesn't work in Eclipse but works in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, eclipse, client-server, serversocket, local-network

Recently I started working with client-server application based on sockets in Java. I got stucked in a problem because Client couldn't establish connection with Server. My Server is Java program in Eclipse on my laptop. Here is server code code:

```
package com.company;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket socketServer = new ServerSocket(8000);
        while(true) {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");
        }
    }
}
```

My laptop is connected to an access point, which is basically my phone (I use my phone as an access point). So my local network consists of my laptop and my phone (as far as I know about local networks). When I try to connect to Server from my phone using this app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplesockettester&hl=uk), there is no connection. "Client connected" is just not written. I connect to server with IPv4 address which I got from ipconfig in command line, so I'm sure that Client is correct. Everything works when I write the same server code in IntelliJ IDEA or when I create Client on the laptop. I think that is Eclipse's bug. Has anyone face this problem? How could I solve it?

Comment: It's unlikely anything directly to do with eclipse. Is your firewall blocking it? It might be considering outgoing traffic as originating from the IDE.

Comment: Check your laptop firewall settings to see if eclipse is blocked for incoming connections.

Comment: Thanks, @Carcigenicate, you helped me. I forgot about firewall. When I disable it everything works. But what if I want to make an exception only for Eclipse? How can  I do it?

Comment: @boot-and-bonnet, It was blocked. Is there any tutorial on how to unblock Eclipse?

Comment: @БогданМагомета That would be operating system specific. In Windows, you would have been prompted the first time it ran. You may have clicked through it accidentally. You'll need to go into the firewall settings and find the rule, or manually create a rule if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: For Macbook, `System Preferences... / Security & Privacy / Firewall / Firewall Options... /` remove java or eclipse entries. You will then be prompted to allow/deny next time you run.